# How to debug in-process IIS in ASP.net Core MVC on VSCode

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code

Since Core 2.2 web applications can truly run in IIS (Express) without using Kestrel in the background. This is called IISHttpServer or the "in-process" hosting model. At the bottom of this question I will put down some articles about this. The last hyperlink in that list of references states that "ASP.NET Core apps default to the in-process hosting model" but that seems not to be the case in my environment.

I would like to debug with the in-process IISHttpServer, especially when it comes to Windows Authentication in Core (without Kernel or HTTP.sys). Unfortunally I can't seem to get this working in Visual Studio Code.

To reproduce, create a new project like this:

```
dotnet new mvc
```

In my .csproj file I add:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
  <AspNetCoreHostingModel>InProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
</PropertyGroup>
```

In the screenshot below you can see that this MVC app still uses Kestrel:

[image: chrome screenshot with server header set to kestrel]

How can I debug IIS in-process hosting with a Core project in VSCode?

When I try this with VS2019, it works fine. The answer might be in the content of launch.json and launchSettings.json as dotnet generates them.

References:

- [Rick Strahl's explanation of in-proces vs out-of-proces](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2019/Mar/16/ASPNET-Core-Hosting-on-IIS-with-ASPNET-Core-22)
- [Microsoft's manual how to host Core on IIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/index?view=aspnetcore-3.0)
- [Another shorter article about in-proces vs out-of-proces](http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/bb086279-ed2a-4628-85f2-7e91125fbe57.aspx)
- [Microsoft's article about ASP.NET Core Module in general](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/aspnet-core-module?view=aspnetcore-3.0)

Answer (score 1):

For Visual Studio it has a complex algorithm to determine how to launch IIS Express (required only by IIS Express), open a web browser (required by IIS to ensure a worker process) and finally attach the debugger to the server process, as well as the browser.

You can hardly emulate the same with `launch.json` and `tasks.json`.

The closest is to define multiple tasks in `tasks.json` to initialize IIS Express and open the web browser to the desired URL. Then in `launch.json` you define a configuration to attach to the server process.

> You might need to run VS Code as administrator if you want to attach to `w3wp.exe` when hosting on IIS.